# response = super().list(request, args, kwargs) explanation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am reading the codebase of the place where I work and in one of the views.py ,i see this line .
Here is the code .

```
class CreditPLansView(mixins.ListModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
  serializer_class = CreditPlansSerializer
  permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

  def get_queryset(self):
        return CreditPlans.objects.all()

  def list(self,request, *args, **kwargs) :
      from hospital.models import ProvidersDiscounts
      response = super().list(request, args, kwargs)
      print("response is", response.data)
```

and here is the value of the response .

```
response is [OrderedDict([('plan_id', 1), ('plan_name', 'Tenure1'), ('months', 3), ('interest', 25)]), OrderedDict([('plan_id', 2), ('plan_name', 'Tenure2'), ('months', 6), ('interest', 25)]), OrderedDict([('plan_id', 3), ('plan_name', 'Tenure3'), ('months', 12), ('interest', 25)])]
```

I need an explanation as what this super().list(request, args, kwargs) is doing and from where is this data coming from .
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you read the docs on the `super` method?

Comment: Hey .I am pretty noob in python as of now .Trying to learn more of it by reading codebase .Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No worries, this video may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo

Comment: A very simplified explanation is that `super().foo()` will call the `foo` method on the super/base classes of the current class, in this example probably the `mixins.ListModelMixin` list method

Comment: A simple logging of super gave super <super: <class 'CreditPLansView'>, <CreditPLansView object>>
.Now this view i tried to trace the model and i see that it refers to some model and these fields are from the same model .

Answer (score 0):

Your `CreditPLansView` is a subclass of `mixins.ListModelMixin` and your `list` method is an overriden version of `mixins.ListModelMixin` 's `list` method.

In `mixins.ListModelMixin`, `list` method returns an HTTP response. So in your code, the author did not want to return the response, but print the output instead.